# two pie chart labels overlapping in matplotlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This is the piece of code i'm having problem with.Here the hp and windows overlap on each other and  makes both of it not visible help me out please

```
plt.figure(0, figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(l_brand_val, labels=l_brand_lab, autopct = "%1.1f%%")
plt.pie(l_os_val, labels=l_os_lab, autopct = "%1.1f%%")
plt.show()
```

[This is the output i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opBgW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You draw two plots on one figure.
Try:
`plt.close()`

```
plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,3])
plt.savefig("test.jpg")
plt.close()
plt.plot([1,2,3], [5,5,5])
plt.savefig("test1.jpg")
```